# Is it possible to test if a method was called without using mocking framework

Tags: java, mocking

I am learning now about the topic Unit Testing in Java and interesting came to me a question that if we can test if a method was called without using Mock or Spy from Mocking Framework.
I mean for example if I have a simple class like

```
class A {
    public void method1(){}
}
```

How can I test if **method1** was called from an instance a?
Do you think is it possible and how can I get that?

Thank you very much

Comment: What you intend to do is behaviour driven testing, some thing that for example Mockito excels at. In order to capure any calls to the target instance, Mockito returns a proxy to the target instance. You would have to do the same manually.

Comment: You could test it indirectly. If the method1() does something, you can check if it has done that something. If no other method has the same effect that means that method1 has been called.

Answer (score 0):

Put this inside method1()

```
System.out.println("[methodname] has been executed :)");
```

Comment: That's a possibility. But you changed the method. And for production you have to remove this output. That's a new source for errors.

Answer (score -1):

In your test class you may inherit from A and override method1 and implement counting behaviour i.e. and use it for your test case